# PyTest - Run each Test as a Mutlitprocessing Process

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, selenium, pytest

I'm using pytest to run my tests, and testing my web application. My test file looks like

```
def test_logins():
    # do stuff

def test_signups():
    # do stuff

def testing_posting():
    # do stuff
```

There are about 20 of them, and many of them have elements that run in constant time or rely on external HTTP requests, so it seems like it would lead to a large increase in testing speed if I could get pytest to start up 20 different mutliprocessing processes (one for each test) to run each testing function. Is this possible / reasonable / recommended?

I looked into [xdist](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-xdist) but splitting the tests so that they ran based on the amount of cores on my computer isn't what I want.

Also in case it's relevant, the bulk of the tests are done using python's requests library (although they will be moved to selenium eventually)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would still recommend using `pytest-xdist`. And, as you mentioned already because your tests mostly do network IO, it's ok to start pytest with (much) more parallel processes than you have cores (like 20), it will be still beneficial, as GIL will not be preventing the speedup from the parallelization.

So you run it like:

```
py.test tests -n<number>
```

The additional benefit of xdist is that you can easily scale your test run to multiple machines with no effort.
For easier scaling among multiple machines, pytest-cloud can help a lot.

Comment: I've since moved onto another testing setup, I'm just going to take it as a given that your answer works.

I think my main issue before is I didn't know you could start more procs than you have cores with xdist